# 'hive on spark' in datastax enterprise DSE?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, hive, datastax, datastax-enterprise

DSE 6 comes pre-bundled Cassandra and SparkSql. Has anyone also setup 'Hive on Spark' there? I wonder about spark version conflicts being an issue. Reason i wan't this is that Hive seems to allow masking/authorization with Ranger but SparkSQL doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer not directly related to setting Hive, etc. but DSE has security (authentication/authorization/...) built-in (see [FAQ](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/security/secFAQ.html)), and it's supported by the all components, including Spark SQL.  If you want to have more granular permissions, you can set [row-level access control](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/security/secRlac.html).

Comment: Is that DSE security for all tables viewed in SparkSQL? I assume tables  pointing at DSEFS are covered but I also need security for some external tables that will point at S3